# How can I open an image and edit the image with C# .Net Compact Framework.

Tags: c#, .net, compact-framework

Is it possible to open an image and edit that image by drawing on the image, means loading an image and just making some scratches on it like we can do that in Windows Paint.

How can I do that in .Net Compact Framework using C# ?

Answer (score 9):

Of course you can. Simply open the image using `Image.FromFile()`, then create a `Graphics` object against this image by using `Graphics.FromImage()` and then use GDI+ methods like `DrawLine()`, `DrawRectangle()`, `DrawString()` etc. to make changes to it. At the end, use `Image.Save()` function to save your changes back to the file.

Something on the following lines:

```
Image img = Image.FromFile("<FILE_PATH>");
using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(img))
    g.DrawLine(Pens.Black, 10,10, 20,20);
img.Save("<FILE_PATH>");
```